# Is there somewhere to download Visual Studio Runtime Merge Modules for previous versions?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, merge-module

I'm building a Windows Installer for a VS2015 project.
VS2015 includes the Merge Modules needed to put the VS2015 runtime library into the installer package, however there are DLLs that I didn't compile that have dependencies on older visual studio runtimes.

I don't have the merge modules for these runtimes in the VS2015 library and so far the only way I've seen suggested is to install previous versions of Visual Studio. This is a tremendous pain, because I'll end up with three, extra, different versions of Visual Studio on my machine (to go with the 2015 and 2017 I've already got).

Surely there must be a handy repository to download old merge modules from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fire up a VM, install and grab file files.  Shouldn't take long at all.

Honestly though I caution against using merge modules.  That's a legacy approach with various issues.  A better safer approach is to create a bootstrapper and redist the vcredist.exe packages instead.

Comment: Yeah - that's what I did instead (pretty straightforwardly via Wix). Even the merge module I did have caused dependencies on DLLs that weren't installed